# Free feed reader with push notifications for iPhone

Tags: gratis, ios, iphone-app, feed-reader

Is there a free feed reader with push notifications for iPhone? 
I am looking to receive a push notification every time a new post appears in a feed. The reasoning and the use case are [explained in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299768/367027).

Some of the apps I have already tried or read about:

- [Boxcar](https://boxcar.io/): 
  Discontinued.
- [Hooks](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id9233533630):
  Does not allow me to specify custom feed links. They have their own feeds.
- [LetMeKnow](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id923353363):
  Requires monthly subscription fee.
- [Inoreader](http://www.inoreader.com/welcome):
  Requires monthly subscription fee.
- [Newsify](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/newsify-your-news-blog-rss-feed-reader/id510153374?mt=8):
  I registered [Stack Overflow JavaScript question feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=javascript&sort=newest), the app did not send me any push notifications. (There is a new post almost every minute). Somewhere in the app it says:

  > Background sync is controlled by iOS, which prioritizes apps that you
  >   open more often. So, you may need to use Newsify manually for a week
  >   or more for background sync and notifications to start.

  I am not sure what that means but I do not think those are the push notifications I am looking for. Other apps that send push notifications do not wait one week before notifying.
- [Blogkeen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blogkeen-rss-reader-for-blogs-with-push/id437002915?mt=8): 
  They claim that they have push notifications. Again I have added the [Stack Overflow JavaScript feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=javascript&sort=newest). Did not receive one notification. Should be at least once per minute.
- [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/):
  Not sure how this will work? Still investigating.

Comment: There are other blogs that asked the same question: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/43qaop/is_there_an_rss_reader_with_push_notifications/), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-RSS-reader-that-supports-push-notification), [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/rss-reader-push-notifications-t3306239), [macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/rss-reader-with-push-notifications.1310951/)

Comment: I want this too. But so far, I can only contribute another dud - I installed [Breaking](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/breaking-news-in-your-today/id953959186?mt=8&at=11l4VG&ct=beautifulpixels) because the spiel sounded like it could do what you ask, but it actually doesn't. I also vaguely remember trying out Feedly.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered https://tickers.cc/ and so far, it works for me.

[image: screen shot of notifications on phone's lock screen] [image: a notification arrived while I was composing this post]

However, setting up a new ticker is rather cumbersome. In brief, you have to create a "ticker", then a "channel" within that, and fill in a number of mandatory fields (including a logo! So I now have a number of SE site logos in my camera roll in case I need them again) and finally (aggravatingly) separately add yourself as a subscriber, and add push notifications for it. But after that, it mostly works.

The ticker sleeps between polls, so for a busy tag like Javascript, you get a batch of notifications pretty much every time it polls the feed. The polling interval is apparently 10 minutes (I have not found a way to configure this).

The default sound is a bit too sharp for my ears, but that's easy to change (though there seems to be a bug there in the current version; it beeps even though I turned off the sound. But I was able to revoke notification sound privileges for this app from the phone's notification settings).

Comment: Adding and then removing a ticker produced some odd glitches but I wasn't able to repro.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the swipe keyboard in the second screenshot, that's [MessagEase](https://www.exideas.com/ME/index.php). It's not perfect but it reduced my screen keyboard swearing by something like 70%.

Comment: Does the latency vary around 10 minutes? Have you seen less, more?  I have played around with IFTTT and pushover. There, the latency is arund 5-6 minutes on average. I have seen as fast as 1 minute and the slowest was at 15 min. Will post an answer about that setup here too.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it announce something happened 5 min ago and the push notioes often appeared 11 min apart. I don't have detailed observations but now that you asked, I can say this much.

Comment: Unfortunately, this app is no longer available from the App Store.